# How to compare every elements in an array with every other element without repetition?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics

I want data to be processed as follows.

Eg.
say data x(i)=[1 2 3 5 2 1].
Comparisons should be elements **INDEX** [1 to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4, 1 to 5, 1 to 6, 2 to 3,2 to 4,2 to 5,2 to 6,3 to 4....]
following the above logic
hence elements values of **distance** = [1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1].

hence elements values of **difference** = [1, 2 , 4 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]. 
I have written the following code for the same but i notice that the final matrix 'b' that i want is always changing size when it should be constant.  I welcome any suggestions

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
% read data set
I= imread('img2.bmp');
G=double(rgb2gray(I));

%choose 2 random numbers
n = 1; 
s = [1 960];
k = round(rand(n,1)*range(s)+min(s));

for i = 1:length(k)
% choose a particular row from a matrix
row_no=k(i);
%G=R(row_no,:);

% compare every element with its neigbour to create distance and difference     matrix 
x1=row_no;
x2=row_no;

        for y1 = 1:length(G)%size(G,2)
                for y2 =1:length(G) %1:size(G,2)
                    distance_Mat(y1,y2) = round(sqrt((y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2));
                    difference_Mat(y1,y2) = 1*(G(x1,y1) - G(x2,y2))^2;
                end
        end

%% now remove repeating comparisons             
b=horzcat(distance_Mat(:),(difference_Mat(:)));
[UniXY,Index]=unique(b,'rows');
DupIndex=setdiff(1:size(b,1),Index);
b(DupIndex,:)=[];
%calculate the cumulative sums and store it in different colums of data matrix
A1 = cumsum(b);
data(:,1)=A1;
end
```

Comment: `squareform(pdist(x'))`?

Comment: What is with the `x2-x1`? That's always zero the way you have it set up...

Comment: It is the Cartesian distance formula for the sake of mathematical integrity i left it untouched. It will in this case always be zero because its one dimensional(Row wise sampling) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the stats toolbox then

```
distance_Mat = squareform(pdist(x'));
```

only does each comparison once and then mirrors the data. You can get just the lower half by

```
tril(distance_Mat,-1);
```

If you don't have the toolbox then try this:

```
I = tril(ones(numel(x)),-1);
[r,c] = find(I);

distance_Mat = zeros(numel(x)); 
distance_Mat(logical(I)) = round(sqrt((x(r)-x(c)).^2)
```

Comment: Hello Dan, Firstly Thank you for your answer. When i use the code this is what i get    for the first colum of the distance matrix 0 1 2 4 1 0.

Comment: Hello Dan, Firstly Thank you for your answer.As mentioned x=[1 2 3 5 2 1] is the training data set. When i use the code this is what i get for the first column of the distance matrix 0 1 2 4 1 0. I assume it is the distance of the first 1 from every other element in the matrix x. 1-1=0(check), 1-2=1(check), 1- 3=2 but not 4(?), now the distance of 1-2 when (2) occurs again is 4 and not 1 and lastly for the second occurrence of 1 is 5 units away from the first occurrence.

Comment: @user3263112 yes - that would be the pairwise distance between `x(1)` and the rest of `x`... where are you getting a `3` from? Do you want the distance of the values in the matrix or the distance of the elements from each other...? I think you should supply a fully worked answer for your example `x`

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity in explaining my problem intially. English is not my native language. i appreciate your help

Comment: You've said you want "`[1-2,1-3,1-5,1-2,1-1,...`" which is exactly `[1,2,4,1,0...` the leading zero is just in the place where you would compare 1 to itself (which never gets done because it's always 0). So if this isn't what you want, then please edit your question to add the fully worked output matrix for that input `x`

Comment: I hope it adds clarity

Comment: so `difference = round(sqrt((x(r)-x(c)).^2)` or `pdist(x)`. `distance` is always predictable and I'm sure you can work it out but you could also just do `pdist(1:numel(x))` for example...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70153/discussion-between-user3263112-and-dan).